# Flowplayer can't mute or loop video

Tags: javascript, video, flowplayer

Flowplayer refuses to recognize the code that will loop the video.

It also won't allow me to remove the pause pause function or mute the volume of the video.

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;"
id="player"></div>
<!-- this script block will install Flowplayer inside previous DIV tag -->
<script>
flowplayer(
"player",
"http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
clip: {
url: "http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv",
autoPlay: true,
autoBuffering: true,
onBegin: function () {
this.setVolume(0);
}
},
play: {
opacity: 0.0,
label: null,
// label text; by default there is no text
replayLabel: null,
// label text at end of video clip
},
// disable default controls
plugins: {controls: null},
// prevent pausing
onBeforePause: function() {
return false;
},
// make the video loop
onBeforeFinish: function() {
return false;
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got mine to work with help from your code, but I added de loop option:

```
// make the video loop
loop: true,
onBeforeFinish: function() {
return false;
}
});
```

Hope it helps.